# Removing correctly from a linux system Eclipse

Tags: linux, java, eclipse, uninstall

I've installed eclipse not via the package manager but decompressing the tar.gz.

Besides the directory and `~/.eclipse/` do I need to remove anything else?

I want to do a fresh installation because I'm having problem due to the fact I've updated Indigo to Juno.

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only thing you have done to install eclipse was extracting a .tar.gz then there isn't any data from eclipse except for ~/.eclipse , the extracted directory and your working directory.

Comment: I've installed plugins and of course there are projects in there

Comment: The plugins should be either in the directory where you extracted eclipse or in the .eclipse directory. Your working directory shouldn't contain anything other than your projects so it should be no problem to leave it as it is. There is a possibility that some plugins have their own configuration directory in your home directory in which case you have to delete them.